# Does SharePoint 2010 Search Index the data in the non-promoted fields of uploaded InfoPath forms

Tags: sharepoint, search, infopath

I have an InfoPath document library in which some fields are promoted while others are not. My question is that which of the following will be indexed by SharePoint basic/enterprise/FAST search.

1. Data in the promoted fields
2. Data in the non-promoted fields
3. Data in the attachments

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No
3. No

The search version (basic, enterprise, fast) doesn't matter.

But on two & three: InfoPath forms ultimately are only XML forms (with the attachments being base64 encoded strings). That means that the SharePoint search with a given XML parser could be able to search through the files. When you activate the search for InfoPath forms you would get the whole content of the InfoPath files (i.e. the whole XML including `<xml... >`), which doesn't make it easier to see the contents. For that you would have to create your own IFilter which tells SharePoint how to parse your InfoPath forms.

See [this discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/c67f08c1-f34b-4015-bf53-f0b769daae75) for some ideas.